# general error: database 'T' not connected

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, hana

I am trying to connect SAP HANA database in MVC, but I'm getting this error.

```
general error: database 'T' not connected
```

This is the code for connection:

```
using (HanaConnection sqlConnection = new HanaConnection("Server='192.168.0.13:30015'; UserName='S'; Password='E'; DATABASENAME='T'"))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
            }
```

What could be the cause of this? I also tried changing my port to

```
30013
```

but got this error:

```
Connection failed (RTE:[89006] System call 'connect' failed, rc=10061:No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I can connect with this connection string using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is no tenant database named 'T' available. If you have not configured this tenant, please try to omit the `databaseName` property and simply connect using

```
new HanaConnection("Server='192.168.0.13:30015'; UserName='S'; Password='E'")
```

Based on the error messages it seems that port `30015` is correct as the first error is originating from the database itself and the second is not.